# MagespaceX Giftvoucher not removed complete

Tags: magento2.4.3

When index I get this error:
"Class Magespacex\Giftvoucher\Model\Source\TemplateOptions does not exist"

I have done this:
php -f bin/magento module:disable --clear-static-content Magespacex_Giftvoucher
...and removed tables in database - and files in server.

Seams to be removed completely and only INDEX is the problem now.

Product EAV index process error during indexation process:
Class Magespacex\Giftvoucher\Model\Source\TemplateOptions does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Class `Vendor\Module\Model\Source\ClassName` is commonly used for source models. It can be declared in the following places:

- XML files (system.xml, di.xml, UI component form)
- a `InstallData` class (install script) or a data patch to add a new custom EAV attribute. For example:

```
$catalogSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    'gift_message_available',
    [
        //...
        'source' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
        //...
    ]
);
```

Install scripts and data patches used for modifying the database schema/data.  Install scripts is the old approach, which is located in `<module dir>/Setup` directory, while the data patch is the new approach since Magento 2.3, located in the `<module dir>/Setup/Patch/Data` directory.

In case you removed the module files completely but the error still related to the source model class, it is likely that the source class was used as a source model for a custom attribute stored in the database. Therefore, you should search the source model class in the `eav_attribute` database table. As the source model class contain backslashes, you need to escape them by replacing `\` with `\\\\`.

You can run the following SQL query to detect the EAV attribute record in the database:

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `source_model` LIKE 'Magespacex\\\\Giftvoucher\\\\Model\\\\Source\\\\TemplateOptionsModel%';
```

Once you get the EAV attribute record, delete it from your database to resolve the issue.

---

For those who have a similar issue, which the class is stored in other columns such as `backend_model`, `frontend_model`, you can run the following SQL query to detect the EAV attribute involved:

```
SELECT *
FROM `eav_attribute`
WHERE (`backend_model` LIKE 'Vendor\\\\Module\\\\Model%' OR `frontend_model` LIKE 'Vendor\\\\Module\\\\Model%' OR `source_model` LIKE 'Vendor\\\\Module\\\\Model%');
```

Remember to replace **Vendor** and **Module** in the query to the vendor name and module name of the class you are looking for.

Comment: If this answer helps you resolve your issue, please mark it as accepted (the check symbol at the top-left corner of my answer). That indicates your issue is solved and helps others with the same issue find the verified answer easily.

Comment: I will try this.